# Loading a type at runtime that inherits a class from the current assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection, system.reflection

When I load an assembly at runtime that contains a class that inherits a class defined in the program that is going to load the assembly, can I cast and store that object as an instance of the inherited abstract class?

```
public class ExternalService : Service {
    string assemblyPath, className;
    Service service;
    public ExternalService(string address, string title, string httpMethode, bool takesArguments,string assemblyPath,string className) : base(address, title, httpMethode, takesArguments) {
        this.assemblyPath = assemblyPath;
        this.className = className;
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
        foreach(Type type in assembly.GetExportedTypes()) {
            if (type.Name == className) {
                dynamic c = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                if(c is Service) {
                    Service s = c as Service;
                    s.Address = address;
                    s.HttpMethode = httpMethode;
                    s.Title = title;
                    s.TakesArguments = takesArguments;
                    service = s;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override void Handle(ServiceContextEventArgs e) {
        service.Handle(e);
    }
}
```

Solved:

This Works.

Comment: " can I cast and store that object as an instance of the inherited abstract class?" have you tried it? what was the outcome? A good question though.

Comment: Well I haven't to be quite honest, but I'd like to know because I'm developing a rather time consuming library which this is a part of.

Comment: when I read your post, it sounds a little like the chicken and egg problem. How can the loaded assembly know that you have defined a class that it inherits? or do you mean you have a varible of the type that the loaded class is inheriting from? Is the posted code that of the loaded class or that of the program that is loading the assembly?

Comment: There's the Service class In the SHS.dll library, now If import that library and write a class 'Foo' that inherits the service class in another library say SHSE.dll can I import SHSE.dll at runtime and create an Instance of Foo and cast as an instance of Service that I would store in an instance of the ExternalService class?

Comment: it's of the program loading the assembly, it's in the same assembly as the Service class